# Why does Windows 7 install audio drivers every single time I plug in my HDMI monitor?

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Whenever I plug my Dell monitor into my Dell laptop, Windows 7 installs some audio drivers for quite a long time. It even tells me so in a pop-up. In case it's relevant, I have my laptop configured to use the laptop's display as the main display and the external monitor as an extended desktop.

Why does Windows need to install these drivers over and over again? Is there anything I can do to make those drivers stay installed?

Update: my monitor doesn't even *have* speakers or an audio input. It only has VGA and DVI connectors in the back. I'm using an HDMI cord connected to the DVI adapter, which came with the monitor. Why does Windows insist on installing an audio driver?

Comment: Does your monitor have built-in speakers?

Comment: Once I got back to the office I checked. Definitely no speakers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like Windows is trying to use a generic driver because it can't find the correct ones. This can lead to it never really completely installing the driver. Then each time you plug in the monitor it tries to install again.

Go to Dell's web site, download and install the driver for the model monitor you are using. Windows should use those drivers next time you plug in the monitor.